# Django can't login user in test with UserFactory

Tags: django, testing

I have a class factory like this:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: f'user_{n}')
```

and in my test:

```
class MyTestView(TestCase):
    def test_my_view(self):
        user = UserFactory(password='1234')
        print(User.objects.all())
        print(user.password)
        login = self.client.login(username='user_0', password='1234')
        print(login)
```

the output of this test is:

```
# ...
<QuerySet [<User: user_0>]>
1234
False
# ...
```

Why my user is not logged in ? 
I can see that the password is not hashed, why ? does the problem come from here ?

Comment: What is the value of User.objects.all()[0].is_active ?

Comment: it says `True` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not create a user like that. Django stores a [*hash* of the passwords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords). You can set a password with [**`.set_password(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password):

```
class MyTestView(TestCase):
    def test_my_view(self):
        user = UserFactory()
        user.set_password('1234')
        user.save()
        login = self.client.login(username='user_0', password='1234')
        print(login)
```

Comment: worked with `set_password` ! without `UserFactory` I create user like this: `User.objects.create_user(username='user1', password='1234')` and I can login the user, why with `UserFactory` I have to use the `set_password` method ?

Comment: @YacineRouizi: because your `UserFactory` just creates a `User` object, and sets the password, whereas `.create_user` uses `set_password` internally: https://github.com/django/django/blob/5f8495a40ab1554e81ac845484da890dd390e1d8/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L139